# QNetworkAccessManager PUT request example needed

Tags: qt, rest, qt5

I have been using QNetworkAccessManager successfully for get and post requests.

But I need to use PUT request to update and external API. This PUT requests needs a json string as part its body to be sent to update a record.

I could not find any working example of a PUT Request using QNetworkAccessManager.

Please help to share a sample code.

Comment: Basically I need to know how to set body in QNetworkAccessManager request. That could solve my issue with put request. thanks.

Comment: Is there something in the documentation that's unclear?

Comment: Yes its unclear, so this question. I couldnt find any mention on how to add body content and send the request.

Comment: I dont understand why its down voted. Its a valid question which will help many people. Help documents regarding put request are not clear.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a way to send Json data in QNetworkAccessManager PUT request.

I formed the required json data and stored that in a QJsonDocument variable. And passed that variable(after converting to utf-8 encoded json document using toJson() ) in the put request.

Here is the working test code I use which I believe will be helpful for somebody attempting this.

```
QVariantMap testMapData["age"] = 35;
QJsonDocument testJsonData = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(testMapData);

QNetworkAccessManager manager;

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://example/member/14"));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QString("application/json"));

QNetworkReply* reply = manager.put(request, testJsonData.toJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#put-3

You can use `QNetworkAccessManager::put(const QNetworkRequest & request, const QByteArray & data)` method for this.

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QByteArray someData = "data";
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://example.com"));
QNetworkReply* reply = manager.put(request, someData);
```

Comment: I dont have any data variables to send with the put request.

I need to send a json string as part of the body. The above code doesnt say how I can attach a value for body of the request and send. 

Example of my PUT request url: http://example.com/member/14 
(14 is member id to udpate)
I need to send the following body json string to update age of the member:

{ "age": 35}
 
I could not find relevant qt documentation on how to pass the body text in REST requests

Comment: I tried using manager.put(request, "{\"age\": 35}"); but it didnt work. 

I also tried using QHttpMultiPart and used setBody() to add my json text to it. But not successful so far.